# How to take a screenshot of entire web page using VC++ 2010?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, webpage-screenshot

Is there a way to take a screenshot of entire webpage using VC++ Win32 application.

Comment: Add more details -- is the web page inside the browser or web control or downloaded programmatically? If browser or web control is involved, what is it?

Comment: @Seva, Yes, it is the web page inside the browser (Internet Explorer 9). And one more thing I have created a toolbar with a button. On toolbar button click I can get current window's screenshot. But no clue about entire web screen.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to communicate directly to the rendering engine. There are several projects that already do this on the web, using [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/). Just google for "webkit page snapshot" and you will see several hits, including [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/), [WebKit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/), etc.

I did not try any of those, but sample screenshots they show on their project pages look like what you are asking for.